# minimum distance from the shore (how to retrieve the "shore vertices")

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, distance, interpolation, polyline-creation

I am student of Statistics, this is my first time using GIS., I am sorry for the stupidity of the question but I browsed online and could not find a satisfactory answer.

I have some spatial data in the format (lat, long, y).
I have noticed that the sea proximity influences the statistics y, Is it possible (and if it is how can you do it) to interpolate the coast and then calculate a minimum distance between the polyline interpolating it and the measurement point?

I can do the interpolation on R if it is complicated on GIS, but how can I retrieve the data of the "vertices" of the shore?
I understand I have to use polygons, but how does that work do I have to do it manually or is there an automatic way?

Please do not say to read the guides, I have read quite enough and I am clearly missing something.

I have downloaded GRASS GIS and have an ArcGIS online account.
My data about the Finland coast come from [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown). country: *Finland*, subject: *Administrative Areas*.

Thanks

Irene

Comment: Not a GRASS user myself but I would try [this](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.distance.html) specifically: v.distance from=points to=coast upload=dist column=dist

Comment: I think GRASS will be a better bet than ArcGIS Online (in ArcGIS for Desktop it would have been easy) so I have tagged your question accordingly.

Comment: I installed the ArcGIS Desktop Free Trial, so go along with the solution. Please enter in details. Thank you again.

Comment: @eseglem solution of Near would be my first choice (+1) using ArcGIS for Desktop but if you really need to access the coordinates of vertices then ArcPy (part of ArcGIS for Desktop) offers the means to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For ArcGIS since you said you installed the trial:

The [Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool does exactly what you are looking for. Your points should go in 'Input Features' and your coastline will go in 'Near Features' the tool will add NEAR_DIST field to your points.

Very important note: "The distances calculated by this tool are in the unit of the coordinate system of the input features. If your input is in a geographic coordinate system and you want output distances to be measured in a linear unit (as opposed to decimal degrees), you must first project your input to a projected coordinate system using the Project tool. For best results, use an equidistant projection or a projection intended for your study area (UTM, for example)."

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing shoreline analysis have a look at DSAS?

http://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/DSAS/